# split 1 record into 4 records(transpose row into column) in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one record in table and i want to split this record into 4 records based on condition(if is Multirecord=1) and  Q has null so no new record needed.(if Q3 is null then 3rd row not required)
and insert into new table.Details are:

Table: emp

```
UID name   is_Multirecord Q1  P1    T1      ....      Q4 P4    T4
1   xyz     1             10  $200 15-03-2019         40 $500  18-03-2019
```

Output in table EMp_split

```
record_no UID  Nae   is_Multi  Q   P     T
1        1      xyz     1      10  $200  15-03-2019
2        1      xyz     1      20  $300   16-03-2019
.....
4.       1      XYZ     1      40   $500  18-03-2019
```

Please assist.Let me know if any other information required.

Comment: See: [UNPIVOT Operator](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1#unpivot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
SELECT UID as record_no, name as Nae, is_multirecord as is_Multi, Q1 as Q, P1 as P, T1 as T
WHERE is_multirecord = 1
UNION
SELECT UID as record_no, name as Nae, is_multirecord as is_Multi, Q2 as Q, P2 as P, T2 as T
WHERE is_multirecord = 1
UNION
SELECT UID as record_no, name as Nae, is_multirecord as is_Multi, Q3 as Q, P3 as P, T3 as T
WHERE is_multirecord = 1
UNION
SELECT UID as record_no, name as Nae, is_multirecord as is_Multi, Q4 as Q, P4 as P, T4 as T
WHERE is_multirecord = 1
```